# Catch Scroll End on Scrollable Div on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I know that the following will fire after the scroll completely stops on iOS devices

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){

    alert('scroll fully stopped');        

});
```

But I want to catch when a scrollable div with *-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;* fully stops scrolling.

I have tried:

```
$('#my-div').bind('scroll',function(){

    alert('scroll fully stopped');        

});
```

But the above fires instantly as soon as I scroll, never waits till the end

How can I catch the end of scrolling on an internal div?

Hope someone can help, it's driving me mad!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could disable touch scrolling and use a plugin like iScroll http://iscrolljs.com/?

```
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { 
    onScrollMove: function() {
        console.log('onScrollMove');
    },
    onScrollEnd: function() {
        console.log('onScrollEnd');
    }
});
```